# javascript code to check special characters

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code to check if special characters are in a string. The code works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome. In Chrome, even if the string does not contain special characters, it says it contains special characters.

```
var iChars = "~`!#$%^&*+=-[]\\\';,/{}|\":<>?";

for (var i = 0; i < chkfile.value.length; i++)
{
  if (iChars.indexOf(chkfile.value.charAt(i)) != -1)
  {
     alert ("File name has special characters ~`!#$%^&*+=-[]\\\';,/{}|\":<>? \nThese are not allowed\n");
     return false;
  }
}
```

Suppose I want to upload a file `desktop.zip` from any Linux/Windows machine.
The value of `chkfile.value` is `desktop.zip` in Firefox, but in Chrome the value of `chkfile.value` is `c://fakepath/desktop.zip`. How do I get rid of `c://fakepath/` from `chkfile.value`?

Comment: refer:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839483/special-character-validation-using-javascript

Comment: i saw this code but my problem is code not working in chrome but working in mozilla.

Comment: use a regex for this. indexOf is ugly...

Answer (score 53):

You can *test* a string using this [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
function isValid(str){
 return !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to remove the apostrophe from this

Comment: Well ... just remove it: `/[~\`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\;,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g`

Comment: If you're using this for passwords, this one has all the special characters defined by OWASP: ```/[\s~`!@#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?()\._]/g.test(str)```

Answer (score 17):

Try This one.

```js
function containsSpecialCharacters(str){
    var regex = /[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/g;
 return regex.test(str);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 13):

Directly from the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) website:

```
   var str = "The best things in life are free";
   var patt = new RegExp("e");
   var res = patt.test(str);
```

To combine their example with a regular expression, you could do the following:

```
function checkUserName() {
    var username = document.getElementsByName("username").value;
    var pattern = new RegExp(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/); //unacceptable chars
    if (pattern.test(username)) {
        alert("Please only use standard alphanumerics");
        return false;
    }
    return true; //good user input
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `new RegExp`

Answer (score 5):

Did you write `return true` somewhere? You should have written it, otherwise function returns nothing and program may think that it's false, too.

```
function isValid(str) {
    var iChars = "~`!#$%^&*+=-[]\\\';,/{}|\":<>?";

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
       if (iChars.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1) {
           alert ("File name has special characters ~`!#$%^&*+=-[]\\\';,/{}|\":<>? \nThese are not allowed\n");
           return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried this in my chrome console and it worked well.

Comment: actually problem is whenever i am browsing a file from local machine via chrome it's taking path like c:/ggg/filename but in mozila it takes only filename chkfile.value shoulnot contain full path

Comment: We should also include tab, backspace.. You can find more special characters at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it this way.

`specialRegex = /[^A-Z a-z0-9]/ 
 specialRegex.test('test!') // evaluates to true`

Because if its not a capital letter, lowercase letter, number, or space, it could only be a special character

Comment: This has the drawback that it does not specify which characters are "special characters". For example, this code considers the character á a special character, although in many contexts, it might not be (for example while checking some French text). So, depending on the context, your solution might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to include any special character, then try this much simple way for checking special characters using RegExp [\W](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-word) Metacharacter.

```
var iChars = "~`!#$%^&*+=-[]\\\';,/{}|\":<>?";
if(!(iChars.match(/\W/g)) == "") {
    alert ("File name has special characters ~`!#$%^&*+=-[]\\\';,/{}|\":<>? \nThese are not allowed\n");
    return false;
}
```