# How to check characters and special chatacerts entered in a textbox in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

In jquery how to check the entered text data contains characters and special characters.if it is there i need to display error message else i need to execute other method.please tell me ?
How to check characters and special characters of a text in jquery ?

Comment: Might this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896599/javascript-code-to-check-special-characters

Comment: i need to check characters and also special characters if any one found need to display error message.

Comment: use a regular expression to test the string.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: by using isnumeric property resoved that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to validate user enter data is numeric or not. so in this case use jQuery.isNumeric(); in Jquery to validate the user enter data.[JQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)