# javascript check if string contains any symbols

Tags: javascript

I have the following set of symbols:

```
var a = '|\/~^:,;?!&%$@*+';
```

How can I check is the following string contains any of those symbols?

```
var b = 'avguybdf';
```

Comment: with a regular expression

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Duplicate [javascript code to check special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896599/javascript-code-to-check-special-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, regular expressions will work.

```
b.match(/[|\\/~^:,;?!&%$@*+]/);
```

EDIT: I originally used the method here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/2044733 to escape the string but because of the grouping, only the backslash character needs to be escaped.

The "/" at the beginning and end of the string are the delimiters for regular expressions in javascript, and "[]" are used to group the characters. In case you're wondering how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RegEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Check the how to use regex @ [Javascript RegEx](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following examples that use regular expressions:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?264705-Best-way-to-check-for-multiple-characters-in-a-string

http://tjvantoll.com/2013/03/14/better-ways-of-comparing-a-javascript-string-to-multiple-values/

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx. You can use test() or exec(). Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp