# Javascript: Find special characters in string

Tags: javascript, string, special-characters

I have this code:

```
        var text = "ß042´ßzpüwhü90hu54/()=?*/()=?*";
        var symboles = "!§$%&/()=?*<;:-<,.-#+|~}][{@€";
        var symbolsContained = "", found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < symboles.length; i++) {
            if (text.indexOf(symboles[i]) != -1) {
                found = true;
                symbolsContained += symboles[i];
            }
        }
        console.log(symbolsContained, symbolsContained.length);
```

Unfortunately it is not working properly:

- symboles[1] finds a character that is not in the list ("A" with a ":" above it)
- The "€" is not processed properly

Using substr() doesn't fix this. I guess it is a subject of character encoding but this is still a mystery for me. Any hint how this can be fixed?

Comment: Use charcodes maybe?

Comment: `/()=?* 6` this is the output I'm getting, what are you expecting ?

Comment: Yes, for these characters it works fine but I used the debugger and found out that
symboles[1] finds a character that is not in the list ("A" with a ":" above it)
and "€" is not processed properly (script finds three cryptic characters at that position).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript code to check special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896599/javascript-code-to-check-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Euro sign I found the solution here:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21092349/Euro-character-in-javascript.html

```
        var symboles = "!§$%&/()=?*<;:-<,.-#+|~}][{@\u20AC";
```

Remains the cryptic character at symboles[1] which also appears in the result. In 11dimension's environment apparently this is not the case.
I have Windows 7 and Opera.