# Check for special characters (, ; .) while validating a form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, special-characters

I tried to insert this piece of code (which I had found on a website) on my (working) validation script:

```
if (register.username.match(/\W/)) {
    alert('You have special characters on username field.');
    return false;
}
```

It did nothing, and it also prevented the whole script from working.

This is the html form (not the whole thing):

```
<form name="register" method="POST" action="registar.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <ul class="left-form">
        <h2>Nova conta:</h2>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="password" name="pass_confirm" placeholder="Confirmar a password" required/>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
        </li>
        <input type="submit" value="Registar">
        <div class="clear"> </div>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And this is my Javscript code (without the special characters checking):

```
function validateForm() {
    if (register.username.value.length <= 2) {
        alert("O username escolhido é demasiado curto.");
        return false;
    }
    if (register.username.value.length > 20) {
        alert("O username escolhido é demasiado longo.");
        return false;
    }
    var x = register.email.value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("O email inserido parece ser inválido.");
        return false;
    }
    if (register.username.value == register.pass.value) {
        alert("Por questões de segurança, pedimos que use uma password diferente do seu nome de utilizador.");
        return false;
    }
    if ((register.pass.value.length < 6) || (register.pass.value.length > 20)) {
        alert("Certifique-se que a sua password tem entre 6 e 20 letras.");
        return false;
    }
    if (register.pass.value != register.pass_confirm.value) {
        alert("As passwords não condizem.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ignore the alerts as they are only the display messages.

Can someone write a piece of code which checks for special characters (! , . + * etc.) or tell me what's wrong with the code I used?

Comment: Please show the HTML of the form and name field.

Comment: And what if my name has those characters in it? ==>

Comment: Just grabbing random script you find on a website and applying it to your code without understanding what it does isn't a successful route to development excellence. Spend some time learning about the language and environment in which you're working, and you'll be able to make these sorts of changes in your sleep. In this case, you're probably looking for [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for that page! I'll be sure to read and study it.

Comment: Do note that I'm a student and all this is new to me. That is why I came to seek help and guidance on this website, as most of my questions were answered here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Special character validation using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839483/special-character-validation-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should change the code to this:

```
if (register.username.value.match(/\W/)) {
   alert('You have special characters on username field.');
   return false;
}
```

What's the difference? Well if you have realized I added `.value` in the middle. Because `register.username` would refer to the username input element and it doesn't have a `match` method. We need to check the text entered in it. By checking [input element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), you can realize we use it's `value` property which returns the text entered. So `register.username.value` is the text entered by the user and since it's a string we can use [`.match` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on it.

You can now pass any regex to the match method that would satify your needs. Check [the guide on regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) also.

Also always check for errors shown in the developer console.

Comment: Thank you! It was a big fail on my part not to notice the missing `.value`, honestly.