# Regular expression to remove bad Character strings

Tags: java, regex, filter

What regular expression can I use to remove the letters `Â` and `Ä` from a String?

Regards,
Raj

Comment: copy and paste the characters from a web page into a string constant in your editor or IDE.

Comment: This is the wrong thing to do. You have asked the wrong question to get the answer you need.

Comment: That looks very suspiciously like an encoding mismatch. The right thing to do is not to delete things like this, but to fix the encoding properly.  I very strongly suggest a 100% UTF-8 workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756567/regular-expression-for-excluding-special-characters), I'd just whitelist these characters:  ^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜ]*$

Answer (score -1):

Java Regexs support unicode, you could find the unicode codes and something like this

```
myNewString = myString.replaceAll("\u0000", "")
```

Comment: **Java regexes do not ‘support Unicode’!** This is a myth. Java merely offers a few features in that direction, but far from enough to make it truly usable.  Unicode support is rudimentary and incomplete in Java. It does not even meet the barebones requirements of [Level 1 support for Unicode Regular Expressions in UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/). Trust me, I know.

Comment: Err... okay, I'll rephrase, you can and probably should use unicode escape sequences rather than putting the actual character in code, I've never had a problem doing this with relatively limited experience.