# Java Regular Expression checking for symbols

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for excluding special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756567/regular-expression-for-excluding-special-characters)

How would I check if a String contains a symbol? let's say I have this String

```
"SUGAR :::: SUGAR"
```

I would want to check if that string contains = the following Symbols

```
":,?,!@#$%^&*()";
```

I tried this

```
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[?,!,@,$,%,^,&,*,(,)]");
         Matcher m = p.matcher("?");
         boolean b = m.matches();
         System.out.println(b);
```

But what if the text contains multiple occurrences of  that symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[:?!@#$%^&*()]");
String  str = "SUGAR :::: SUGAR";
Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("string contains pattern");
}
```

The above will check if any part of the string contains *at least* one occurrence of any of the symbols in the pattern (no need to separate them with `,`).

Comment: that is what I did. few minutes ago. but what if it contains multiple occurrences?

Comment: You want to count them or what? Please be a bit more specific, on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: what is the use of ',' ?

Comment: @KyelJmD what do you mean? the pattern will match anyway, it doesn't matter if it contains one or more occurrences, as long as it contains at least one

Comment: @KyelJmD the pattern contains a `,` because it was in the original question, I assumed it's one of the symbols to be matched. If that is not the case, you can remove it.

Comment: I was thinking that "," is a separator.

Comment: @KyelJmD no, `,` is not a separator (there is no need for one!) inside a character class (the characters surrounded by `[...]` in a regular expression). I updated my answer removing the `,` as is not needed.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I tried to type this "::" but it it didn't return true.I thought if it see one occurrences in the pattern it would return false but how come i returned true?

Comment: So the caret character(^) does not count as negation if not at the start of a regex, right? The string "$#@" would match a pattern like [:?!@#$%^&*()] but would not match a pattern like [^:?!@#$%&*()].

Answer (score 1):

guava may be?

```
 CharMatcher matcher = CharMatcher.anyOf(":,?,!@#$%^&*()");
 boolean result = matcher.matchesAnyOf("SUGAR :: SUGAR");
 System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply match against a set containing these characters: `[:,?!@#$%^&*()]`

If you want to check against the symbol `-`, position it to the end of the set: `[...-]`

There's no need to separate elements in a set by comma.

If you want to check for ANY non alphanumeric use \W instead: [\W_] (because \W does not match _)