# Replacing all non-alphanumeric characters except some characters

Tags: java, replace

I want to replace all non-alphanumeric characters, but keep Æ, Ø, Å, æ, ø, å.
Current code:

```
  replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}", "_")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match non-english characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use explicit white list instead:

```
replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9ÆØÅæøå]","_")
```

Look at the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756567/regular-expression-for-excluding-special-characters)

Comment: Dosen't work. This one just replace all alphanumeric characters (and Æ,Ø,Å,æ,ø,å) single character to "_". I want to replace all non-alphanumeric characters except Æ,Ø,Å,æ,ø,å. You did opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Does below work for ya?

```
 replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9ÆØÅæøå]", "_")
```

Comment: You forgot '-numeric' part )

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
replaceAll("^[a-zA-ZÆØÅæøå]*$", "_");
```