# Reading a line ignoring special values

Tags: java

How can I extract each String from  `A B -> carry sum` without  `->` ? So, I need to get only `A` `B` `carry` `sum`. How can it be done?

`A B -> carry sum` is passed as a String into the method.

```
public void parseContactsLine(String line)
{
    Scanner readLine = new Scanner(line);

    while(readLine.hasNext())
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756567/regular-expression-for-excluding-special-characters help?

Comment: Im not familiat with regex @Andy

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string using the `split()` method:

```
public void parseContactsLine(String line)
{
    Scanner readLine = new Scanner(line);

    while(readLine.hasNext())
    {
        String[] parts = line.split("->");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(parts[0].split("\\s+")[0]); // Split string by whitespaces
        int b = Integer.parseInt(parts[0].split("\\s+")[1]);            
        int carry = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim().split("\\s+")[0]);
        int sum = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim().split("\\s+")[1]);
        // Do whatever you want with a, b, carry and sum
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could break the string around the spaces, and ignore the -> you could use regex, use the string.split function, or even iterate over the string and do it yourself

Comment: You know that each input will have 5 strings separated by sources, you know that the third one is the arrow. It sounds like you are doing this for a class, so implementing the function yourself is ideal